# How to create a burp shortcut on your windows desktop

Tags: security, java, web-application, proxy-server, command-line-tool

I have been trying to figure out how to get a windows shortcut for burp. If anyone else can figure out a different way instead of java -jar -Xmx768m "C:\tools\burpsuite_free_v1.6.32.jar"

Answer (score 3):

- Create directory C:\tools
- Download Burp to C:\tool\
- Create a file called burp.vsp in notepad that contains the follow
  - Adding the following to burp.vsp 
                  Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")  
                  WshShell.Run chr(34) & "C:\tools\BurpSuite.bat" & Chr(34), 0 
                  Set WshShell = Nothing
- Create file BurpSuite.bat in C:\tools\
  - Add the follow 
                 java -jar -Xmx768m "C:\tools\burpsuite_free_v1.6.32.jar
- Download burp icon from google
- Go to desktop and right – new -  click shortcut
  - What Item would you like to create a shortcut for 
                
                C:\tools\RunBurp.vbs
  - What would you like to Name the shortcut  
                Burp Suite or whatever you want.
- Change Icon
  - Right click properties
  - Change icon button
    - Find a burp icon and save it as .ico in paint.
- Double click on newly create desktop icon

Done!

Comment: This one is tested and works for me. Thanks for the inputs for this one here. Also, the heap memory for Java doesn't pass more than 1G? I'm having trouble with 1G and Burp hangs when more of spidering and scanning is done. Half-way it hangs and therefore, I am unable to save work.

Comment: you could also use a wrapper like [launch4](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) which will make an executable for most OS:es and allows you to specify VM options. But I've never used it

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on your desktop, go to new, then shortcut. Paste in the line that you posted:

`cmd /c java -jar -Xmx768m "C:\tools\burpsuite_free_v1.6.32.jar"`

And press next, give it a name, then press finish. Done.

[Edited to include `cmd /c` at the beginning to force command prompt mode]

**Edit 2**: If you want the command prompt window to stay open on close, replace `/c` iwth `/k`.

Comment: Actually that doesn't give you the cmd prompt that burp recommends see the docs https://portswigger.net/burp/help/suite_gettingstarted.html

Comment: @bdawg If you absolutely need to run it from a command prompt then put `cmd /c` in front so it looks like this instead: `cmd /c java -jar -Xmx768m "C:\tools\burpsuite_free_v1.6.32.jar"`

Comment: That's what WshShell.Run  does it runs it at the windows shell and runs the bat file

Comment: @bdawg The Windows Scripting Host is overkill for this type of situation. Even the batch file is technically overkill and you could have used either one without the other but you're using both which is extreme overkill. Just create a simple shortcut with the given command.